# How to store metadata about files on sdcard?

Tags: android, metadata, storage

I am planning to create a voice recorder app. I will store my file on the sd card. And I want to store some metadata about them. Name, description, etc. How should I do it? I was thinking to create an SQLite db, and store the metadata there, but what if a file gets deleted, from outside of the applictaion (sd card gets removed), how do I update the DB?

Comment: After retrieved data from database just check for existence of the file. If file not exist then removed data from database. Also always scan a directory for particular file entry in database, If file is present and you don't have data records then enter it.

Comment: Doesen't it makes the app too slow? Also how often do you think I should check the consistence of my DB?

Comment: Yes, It makes your app slow, on the basis of your database operation. Also for this you have to check DB consistency when you have to use those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar sineario. What I have done is used a [file observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) within a service. The service runs the whole time. You can assign a directory to the file observers and you receive onEvent() when something happens